# How to calculate multiple selected Datavalue from Listbox in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

Basically I'm trying to make a quiz application (multiplechoice questions) and I want to calulate the total number of correct answers based on the data value from the database. 
So I've used Listbox inside a repeater to show the choices which looks like the following:

```
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">                
            <ItemTemplate>
              Q-<%# Eval("Question_Text") %><br />

                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" CssClass="listboxCSS"></asp:ListBox><br /> <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

and the C# code look like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlCalss Obj = new SqlCalss();
        Repeater1.DataSource = Obj.ExecuteCmdSelect("SELECT * from Questions where ExamId=1");
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    string choice = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Question_Id").ToString();
    SqlCalss Obj = new SqlCalss();
    DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
    Ds = Obj.ExecuteCmdSelect("SELECT * from Choices where QuestionId="+choice);

    ListBox ListBox1 = (ListBox) (e.Item.FindControl("ListBox1"));
    ListBox1.DataSource = Ds;
    ListBox1.DataTextField = "Choice_Text";
    ListBox1.DataValueField = "Answer";
    ListBox1.DataBind();}
```

The code works good, it show multiple question ( it depends on the quiz) with multiple choices for each question shown in a Listbox.
now for each question,the DataValueField can have only one of two values( 0 = wrong , 1= correct ). In addition the total number of questions is different from one survey to another so I don't know how many Listboxes are there.

How can Add a button that Calculate all the selected datavalues to show the total correct answers ?
I tried this code:

```
   int x = Repeater1.Controls.Count(x => x.DataValueField == 1);
```

and this

```
int numCorrect = Repeater1.Items.Count(x => x.DataValueField == 1);
```

**Edit:**

When I run the web page, for example a quiz that has two questions ( each question has four choices in listbox )
I found that when I view the source of the web page it creates two listboxes with the same name like this:

```
                    <select size="4" name="Repeater1$ctl00$ListBox1" id="Repeater1_ListBox1_0" class="listboxCSS">
....
                    <select size="4" name="Repeater1$ctl01$ListBox1" id="Repeater1_ListBox1_1" class="listboxCSS">
```

and I figured out how to get the value of the first one using code like this:

```
  ListBox ListBox1 = (ListBox)this.FindControl("Repeater1$ctl00$ListBox1");
  Response.Write(ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Is there anyway that I can get the all values of listboxes that has same name?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You'll have to look at the *selected item* of the list box and see if the selected value is 1 or 0. BTW, how did you come to choose such an old framework as webforms for this?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do but couldn't figured it out! I tried to look at the selected items using the code above but did not work. unfortunately I do still do not know how to use MVC. is there any other way to implement this? @Crowcoder .. thanks in advance!

Comment: [Look at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield?view=netframework-4.7.2). `DataValueField` has a `SelectedValue` property. `DataValueField` itself will never be == 1. It's been a long time since I've done webforms (this isn't MVC) but try `(int)DataValueField.SelectedValue`

Comment: the problem i'm facing now is how to access all the listboxes. I made some edits on my question so can you please have a look at it. it may give more clarification about my problem.@Crowcoder thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think `ListBox ListBox1 = this.FindControl("ListBox1") as ListBox` should be enough, no need to use jumbled auto-generated name like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all!
I just found the answer of my problem which is getting by getting all the listboxes in web page using the following code:

```
    private void GetControlList<T>(ControlCollection controlCollection, List<T> resultCollection)
where T : Control
    {
        foreach (Control control in controlCollection)
        {
            //if (control.GetType() == typeof(T))
            if (control is T) // This is cleaner
                resultCollection.Add((T)control);

            if (control.HasControls())
                GetControlList(control.Controls, resultCollection);
        }
    }
```

Then I can get the values using the following:

```
   int s=0;
List<ListBox> allControls = new List<ListBox>();
        GetControlList<ListBox>(Page.Controls, allControls);
foreach (var childControl in allControls)
        {
            s +=  Int32.Parse( childControl.SelectedValue);
        }
```